# How to download URLs that fit a pattern with urllib3

Tags: python, urllib3

I'm trying to use the urllib3 package to download URLs that each fit a specific pattern. I'm trying to download .csv files from many URLs, each of which is of the format https://website.com/data/something.pdf where the "something" changes. How might I automate this?

Comment: do you have a list of what the 'something' is ? If not how do you know what is 'something' (imagine you are doing it manually). If that list is in some webpage you can parse that webpage and extract all the 'something's and then loop through it requesting the file specifically.

Comment: No, I don't have a list—I just need to download all the files from that URL. Is there a way to get everything that fits a certain format?

Comment: Does the base URL https://website.com/data/ contain clickable links to the pdf files? If so, it is possible to get the base URL, extract all the 'something' and download one by one. If you don't have a source where you can get the 'something' from (as the base URL) then it is not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "that fits a certain format"? What's the format? You'll need to generate some sort of list of urls, either by parsing the website manually or in code.

Comment: There is not a list of clickable links—ít's a drop-down menu, and there are many options. Then, after selecting one option, you click "download" or something similar and get the URL. Would there be a way to automate this?

Comment: That's good! Can you provide access to that link ?  If not search for the python library beautifulsoup4 - it will help you extract all the links you need and then run a loop to download each with the urllib3

Comment: Thank you. I'm using this website: https://voterportal.sos.la.gov/graphical and then I select a particular election, go to "Download Results", select "Precinct", and then click "Download Race". How could I use beautifulsoup4?

Comment: This is not the easiest website to parse - has lots of javascript embedded. It would take me too long - so my suggestion would be to use a browser simulator where you can dictate the steps and automate it. Selenium might be the way to go. It is possible but a bit tricky. Hope it helps.